# What troubleshooting steps can be tried if sound is disabled in Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I have installed the Tor Browser on my system.

**System Details**

Windows 11 (64-bit)

- I downloaded the latest Tor Browser available from its official site.
- I am unable to find the steps to enable sound on any site.

**What I Have Tried**

- I attempted to access various video sites.
- I tried installing the latest version of Tor from the official Tor site.

**Notes:** Sound on my Windows system is functioning properly. I also tested other browsers, and the sound plays fine on those sites and browsers.

Comment: Are you sure it is disabled and not simply failing to work?